# Can't see the armature

Tags: armature

I made a character based on a tutorial, idk what i clicked or what happened but i can't see my armature, i tried unhiding(it doesn't even show if it is hided or no).
It only shows in weight painting, but not in pose mode.
If i select my character in pose mode i can move it so bones are there.
[image: armature]

Answer (score 2):

Probably you see an "empty" armature because an empty bone layer has been selected.

[image]

Comment: Please upload your file https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you answered your question, but in my case this was the issue:

The "Objects/bone" was unchecked.

[image]